# Django Channels - execute something when a WebSocket is "closed"

Tags: django, django-channels

I'm using **WebsocketConsumer**, and storing data user-related on the cache layer

And when the **WebsocketConsumer** disconnected, I clean everything related to the user

```
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer


class MyConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):

    def connect(self):
        self.store_session_data()

    def disconnect(self, _):
        self.clean_session_data()
```

The problem is, if either the browser's tab, or the browser itself is closed, disconnect won't be triggered

**Question**

Is there a way to execute something no matter how the **WebsocketConsumer** is closed?

Any thought?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **websocket_disconnect** along side with **disconnect**, I was able to properly clean the session data no matter how the connection was closed

```
class MyConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):

    def connect(self):
        self.store_session_data()

    def disconnect(self, _):
        self.clean_session_data()

    def websocket_disconnect(self, message):
        self.clean_session_data()
        super().websocket_disconnect(message)
```

---

**Update:**
calling `super().websocket_disconnect(message)` is required to proper disconnect